# How to get selected values from dropdown in observer.php

Tags: php, magento

How can you get selected values from a drop down menu in grid page of any custom admin module ?
(we want selected value to be displayed under grid (for e.g status drop down --- enabled is displayed by default))

Answer (score 0):

considering you dont have any JS plugins which allow multiple selections in the drop-down, give the dropdown menu a `name` attribute and value (say `name='drop_down1'`, and using $_POST/$_GET (whatever you are using), access it in the php file as $_POST['drop_down1'] or $_GET['drop_down1']. This will give you the sole value selected.